# Easily add an '(all)' facet to facet_wrap in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this example in the [`facet_wrap` documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html):

[image]
<sub>(source: [ggplot2.org](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap-29.png))</sub>

I would like to fill the last facet with the overall view, using all data.

Is there an easy way to add a 'total' facet with `facet_wrap`? It's easy to add margins to `facet_grid`, but that option does not exist in `facet_wrap`.

Note: using `facet_grid` is not an option if you want a quadrant as in the plot above, which requires the `ncol` or `nrow` arguments from `facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = transform(mpg, cyl = as.character(cyl)))
cyl6 <- subset(mpg, cyl == 6)
p + geom_point(data = transform(cyl6, cyl = "7"), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(data = transform(mpg, cyl = "all"), colour = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Would you also know how hard is it to change `all` to another string? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Perfect, works as expected. Didn't know the `transform` tricks (also learning about `mutate` on the same occasion). Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer a slightly alternative approach. Essentially, the data is duplicated before creating the plot, with a new set of data added for the all data. I wrote the following `CreateAllFacet` function to simplify the process. It returns a new dataframe with the duplicated data and an additional column `facet`.

```
library(ggplot2)

#' Duplicates data to create additional facet
#' @param df a dataframe
#' @param col the name of facet column
#'  
CreateAllFacet <- function(df, col){
  df$facet <- df[[col]]
  temp <- df
  temp$facet <- "all"
  merged <-rbind(temp, df)

  # ensure the facet value is a factor
  merged[[col]] <- as.factor(merged[[col]])

  return(merged)
}
```

The benefit of adding the new column `facet` to the original data is that it still allows the variable `cylinder` to be used to colour the points in the plot within the aesthetics:

```
df <- CreateAllFacet(mpg, "cyl")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=displ,y=hwy)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=cyl))  +
  facet_wrap(~ facet) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

you can try "margins" option in facet_wrap as followings :

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = transform(mpg, cyl = as.character(cyl)))
cyl6 <- subset(mpg, cyl == 6)
p + geom_point(data = transform(cyl6, cyl = "7"), colour = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~ cyl, margins=TRUE)
```