# Control which samples to be included in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to split my data into two facets based on `pairs`. The samples that are included in the facet pairs=Yes, should ALSO be plotted in the facet pairs=None. 
By default `ggplot` does not do this, rather the samples plotted in one facet is not plotted in the other.

```
ggplot(df,aes(type,as.numeric(value), fill=type)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(~pairs)


            type  value                     pairs
1           Tumor 13.9012545838285          None
2           Normal 11.0978149433342         None
3           Normal 12.9807255911136         None
4           Tumor 17.7120374094025          None
5           Tumor 18.4255385552523          None
7           Tumor 14.4260579858951          Yes
8           Normal 14.4260579858951         Yes
```

Comment: *"rather the samples plotted in one facet is not plotted in the other"* Yes, that's how `facet_grid` works. I don't understand your question. If you don't want two facets for `pairs=Yes` and `pairs=None`, then why use `facet_grid`? Can you provide a mock-up of your expected output?

Comment: Why `as.numeric(value)`?

Comment: Found the slution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933575/easily-add-an-all-facet-to-facet-wrap-in-ggplot2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a dummy variable that only expresses which facet you want each sample to participate in?

```
ggplot(data.df,aes(type,as.numeric(value), fill=type)) +
    geom_boxplot(data=data.df%>%mutate(whichfacet="f1")) + #all samples participate in facet f1
    geom_boxplot(data=data.df%>%filter(pairs=="Yes")%>%mutate(whichfacet="f2")) + #only yes samples in facet f2
    facet_grid(.~whichfacet)
```

Comment: Thanks. Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933575/easily-add-an-all-facet-to-facet-wrap-in-ggplot2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa